# In Java, can I make a predicate that applies a filter on more than one object?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, predicate

I have a predicate that I use to filter a list of the same Entity Object:

```
Predicate<DWHDeal> companyFilter = i -> i.getCompany().equals(company);
```

I also have to apply the same filter, with the exact same condition on the exact same field, on a list of DTOs where the DTOS is built based on the entity from before:

```
Predicate<DWHDealDTO> companyFilterDTO = i -> i.getCompany().equals(company);
```

Is it possible to achieve this without instancing two different predicates? If possible, I would like to achieve this by making only one `Predicate`.

Comment: Are `DWHDealDTO` and `DWHDeal` related? (like extending the same class)

Comment: Does `getCompany()` return the same type in both cases?

Comment: @ernest_k No, they don't extend the same classes unfortunately. But they have mostly the same fields.

Comment: @Ruslan yes, a String.

Comment: And what about defining a common interface ? (i.e. implemented by both classes)

Comment: @Benoit they don't have a common interface.

Comment: @Benoit That wouldn't be possible unfortunately, i have to follow my client's (who is a developer himself) guidelines and he would not approve that.

Comment: The rules are not different to, e.g. implementing the `Predicate` with an ordinary class or trying to write a method accepting both, `DWHDeal` and `DWHDealDTO`, as parameter. If these classes have no common interface or superclass declaring a common method, they don’t have a common method, just two unrelated methods which happen to have the same name.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `getCompany()` returns a `String` you could create `Predicate<String>`:

```
Predicate<String> predicate = s -> s.equals(company);
```

And then using it like:

```
list.stream()
    .filter(dto -> predicate.test(dto.getCompany()))
    ...
```

But there is not much benefit since it requires almost the same code.

Comment: It does have a benefit. Instead of creating Predicates for every DTO, only one Predicate is enough with this approach for all the DTOs. So this leads to better code reusability. Less code written means less code to manage.

Comment: @KetanR this still has a predicate for every DTO, to be precise, this has even one more predicate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need a `Function<T,R>` before using `Predicate` :

There are two concepts to Function. First is a `java.util.function.Function` which accepts **one** argument and produces a *result*. The second is stream intermediate operation map which converts each element in a **stream** into **another object** via the supplied function.

In your case the `Function` should look like :

```
Function<DWHDeal, DWHDealDTO> myFunction = new Function<DWHDeal, DWHDealDTO>() {
  public DWHDealDTO apply(DWHDeal t) {
    return ... ;
  }
};
```

---

I tried the basic Program as below with success:

```
static class DWHDeal{
    String name;

    public DWHDeal(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }
  }
  static class DWHDealDTO{
    String name;

    public DWHDealDTO(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }
  }

  static Predicate<DWHDealDTO> companyFilter = i -> i.name.equalsIgnoreCase("com");
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Function<DWHDeal, DWHDealDTO> myFunction = new Function<DWHDeal, DWHDealDTO>() {
      public DWHDealDTO apply(DWHDeal t) {
        return new DWHDealDTO("com");
      }
    };
    DWHDeal newDWHDealDTOObj = new DWHDeal("com");
    System.out.println(companyFilter.test(myFunction.apply(newDWHDealDTOObj)));  //Works
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, the common interface would be the preferred solution.

I guess you could do something like this, but to be fair, it is ugly.

```
private String getCompany(Object o) {
    if(o instanceof DWHDeal)
        return ((DWHDeal) o).getCompany();
    else
        return ((DWHDealDTO) o).getCompany();
}
```

---

```
Predicate<Object> companyFilter = i -> getCompany(i).equals(company);
```

Answer (score 0):

If equality is only check then you can use static  Predicate isEqual(Object targetRef). see java doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#isEqual-java.lang.Object-

```
class StudentView{
    String name;

    public StudentView(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
class StudentDTO{
    String name;

    public StudentDTO(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public void testPredicate(){
    StudentView studentView= new StudentView("John");
    StudentDTO studentDTO = new StudentDTO("Sam");
    Predicate p = Predicate.isEqual("John");
    System.out.println("Test for Student View "+ p.test(studentView.name));
    System.out.println("Test for Student DTO "+ p.test(studentDTO.name));


}
```